# how to read values from JSON nested in multiple arrays

Tags: java, json

I have below JSON Data which constitutes inner array
How to read data from Inner Array

```
{
TRANSACTION:[
{ 
listEditions: [
{
"adRoute":"B",
"listInsertion":[
    {
        "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},

{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
}
],

listPackage: 
[
{

listEditions: [
{
"adRoute":"B",
"listInsertion":[
    {
        "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},

{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
}
]
}],

referenceID: E13F42EC5E38 
}
]
}
```

I am accessing URL which returns me data in above JSON format
I want get values from that Array listEdition and An array listInsertion in side that Edition Array
and same from that listPackage  array which has that full listEdition array.

Comment: This is not valid JSON; object member names must be JSON strings

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the answer with a correct json, but the one befor was not valid. If you were using that one you have to fix that!

Comment: can anybody guide me how to get all those values from above JSON

Comment: can anybody help me with source code

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listEditions.length; i++)
        {
          var arrayItem=item.listEditions[i].listInsertion;

        //get colorType value 
            alert(arrayItem[0].colorType);
       //get color value
            alert(arrayItem[0].color)
        }
```

i think it will meet your demand.you can see the example:http://jsfiddle.net/rayhan/x2H5W/